# Replace CM13 recovery with CWM6

Tags: cyanogenmod, 6.0-marshmallow, clockworkmod-recovery

I am using Sony Xperia SP codename Huashan with Android 6.0.1 running cyanogenmod 13. When I flashed the custom ROM for CM13 it replaced the CWM recovery with its own CM13 recovery. How do I regain CWM recovery on my device. Will installing the CWM Recovery in fastboot mode break my CM13.

I followed the below link

http://techbeasts.com/install-cwm-6-recovery-on-xperia-sp-running-12-1-a-0-266-firmware-how-to-guide/

for installing CWM but the author says that it is only for stock ROM and now I am on custom ROM CM13. Will this procedure still work?

Answer (score 2):

> Will installing the CWM Recovery in fastboot mode break my CM13?

No, why would it? But before flashing your custom recovery make sure to disable the setting *Update Cyanogen recovery* or *Update CM recovery* or a similar setting under [developer-options](/questions/tagged/developer-options). Afterwards, flash your custom recovery the way you want. If that doesn't work, flash a custom kernel followed by your custom recovery.

A custom recovery is not limited to a particular ROM so it doesn't matter whether you're using stock ROM or not.

Comment: As a side note: several places even recommend replacing CM recovery by TWRP (e.g. for the *Wileyfox Swift* which ships with CyanogenOS, many of the tutorials for switching to CyanogenMod do so).

Comment: I did flash a custom recovery CWM on my CM 13 but that led to my phone not booting in so I flashed Doomlord's kernel